# Multiple gravity assists

Tags: gravity-assist

Is it possible,just by looking at the heliocentric position and velocity vectors of the spacecraft and the planet,to decide whether the resulting flyby would be trailing or a leading flyby? If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Space! This question is way too broad for this site. If you have a look around at other questions you'll see that questions are generally focused on specific issues, and will usually show some amount of independent work or research. Right now your question would require several chapters of a book to answer. I'd recommend you re-edit your question and add in as much specific information from the assignment as you can, and then add in what you have tried so far and what else you've read about the problem.

Comment: You can also click the `gravity-assist` tag below your question and it will take you to 78 other questions here about gravity assist, most of them have good answers. I know it's hard when you are just starting out on a new topic, try several sources and see which one seems to be most helpful in your case.

Comment: You may find [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12424/20636) answer to the [Titan trajectories options](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/titan-trajectories-options) helpful

Comment: @JCRM...I did use the NASA Trajectory Browser for the launch windows to Venus since I am planning to do a flyby about Venus. But the transfer ellipse I am getting has Time of Flight which does not match that window. What do I do?