# What should be the mission plan in order to reach TITAN (SATURN) by a group of 15 people for Scientific Exploration?

Tags: propulsion, planetary-science, titan, saturn

I am working on a project where we have to design a
**Mission to TITAN by Digitally construct and document the development of a six-month long human settlement on Titan (Moon), bearing the capability to be a source of strength to extra-terrestrial human life sustainability and adequately equipped with scientific requirements for research execution.**

I have attached the topics which are to be considered while designing the mission. The content should not be very complex. The project is just a test to how well a mission can be planned (no great scientific knowledge is required; this project is done by Freshman).

I had been facing issues with certain things and need input from community.

I studied the trajectory and orbital part. I got confused as to what should I consider (Like I have of travelling thought of a spaceship like the one in LOST IN SPACE or the one in INTERSTELLAR). I planned to use Gravitational Slingshots but confused between using inner planets or Mars. For later part I know a assist from Jupiter to Saturn is must to reach Titan. One this trajectory part is completed I have problem with how do I reach TITAN from SATURN. What should be the method and process followed? While researching I stumbled upon terms such as Hohmann Transfer, Orbeth Transfer etc. and curious to know how can I apply them in this mission?

To summarize, if the community can help me with designing the trajectory and entire duration for the mission, it would help me resolve the issue I am facing.

I am also open to receiving suggestions for other subtopics from the image attached.

[image: Subtopics]

Comment: I think an entire mission plan for a crewed mission to Titan and a base they live in for six months is too much to expect from a single Stack Exchange question. This is way too broad.

Comment: Question and answer re: Titan trajectories: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/titan-trajectories-options

Comment: @uhoh I understand. If only the community can help me with the trajectory design would be more than helpful. I am done with the other topics drawing inspirations from other scientific missions planned / cancelled to titan.

Comment: Okay can you edit the question and make it clearer how narrow the scope is? Perhaps you can separate the actual question from the background material. It's great to add context and background but see if you can make a clear separation between the two. It's quite possible that the question can be reopened in that case.